# Did the tafsir made a mistake? or there is an interdmediate state between minor and adult?

Tags: quran, fiqh

I really dont understand a verse of the quran and his tafsirs.

The verse 6 surah 4 stated that you test the orphan until the mariage.
And according to the tafsirs it s PUBERTY
We know that when a boy has his first wet dream he becomes FULLY RESPONSIBLE of his acts according to a hadith.

ok so what s up with the following part of the verse

"then if you perceive in them sound judgement, release their wealth to them. "

So the boys  who  supposely already reached puberty  isn't mature yet to manage his own propety

Answer (score 2):

رشد can come with puberty or after it. It is possible for an adult to not have sound judgement, as there are adults who are stupid or wasteful spenders - in that case their property will not be handed over to them rather their guardian will continue to manage it and will keep testing them.

Comment: thanks you very much ,  there is an intermediate state which you arent mukkalaf yet while you reached puberty?
Can you give me the different name or souce about this because I didnt find any tafsir of book which explain that clearly 

But this doesnt contradict the hadith saying puberty = fully  responsible
I need to read more about this it s very interesting

Comment: Its not about being mukkalaf, its only about being allowed to spend. Allah has put two conditions on releasing property of orphans: (i) puberty and (ii) sound judgement regarding wealth, the property is not released over until both are met because otherwise it is possible that the person will financially ruin himself because of lack of experience.

Comment: thanks you but if you reach puberty you are fully responsible right?
so why allah stated that you need to give their wealth just when they are mature?
You told me it s the case if they reached puberty but they are crazy or stupid .
Ok then why we would have married someone who sn't mature yet?!

because in the verse 6 ,the marriage part and the part where you give their wealth back are linked with  " FA ina" in english translation they wrote " THEN'